# Partes do Stack Overflow PT em Inglês

Tags: bug, tradução

Vejo que recentemente algumas partes do StackOverflow ficaram em inglês:

[image]

Esse é só um dos exemplos. Isso é esperado?

---

*Obs:* Vejo que há uma falta de tradução há vários dias.

Comment: Ta mesmo, inclusive abaixo do seu nome, tem um "new contributor". A SE é assim mesmo, lança as coisas e dane-se a comunidade internacional, q tem que descobrir e se virar para traduzir